# Filter parents according to count of child respecting some criterias

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables :

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    min_quantity = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
    children = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Child', backref=sqlalchemy.orm.backref('parent')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    expiration_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
    parent_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('parents.id'))
```

What is the simplest way to select only Parent objects that have at least min_quantity children with an expiration_date < datetime.today() ?

I could query every Parent objects and then do a list comprehension :

```
parents = session.query(Parent).all()
ok_parents = [parent for parent in parents if len([child for child in parent.children if child.expiration_date < datetime.today()]) > parent.min_quantity]
```

But it doesn't feel like really efficient code.

I suppose I can do that in only one query with the good options, and I suspect I will have to use having() in my query, but since my knowledge of sqlachemy (and SQL in general) are still limited, I didn't manage to solve this problem.

So basically, I'm open to any proposition.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that you could employ a HAVING clause. In addition you could for example query parents joined with children, filter those by expiration date, group by parent id, and filter the groups by count of rows per group in relation to min quantity:

```
ok_parents = session.query(Parent).\
    join(Child).\
    filter(Child.expiration_date < datetime.today()).\
    group_by(Parent.id).\
    having(func.count(1) > Parent.min_quantity).\
    all()
```

A caveat in the above query is that a parent with no children can not be a result because of the inner join. To work around that you'd use `outerjoin(Child)` and filter the resulting rows by either having no child (`Child.id.is_(None)`), or expiration date.